Verification of electron variable mass and charge from universe observations
Recently I have skimmed a very interesting article "On the same origin of quantum physics and general relativity from Riemannian geometry and Planck scale formalism", which tries to unite general relativity with quantum mechanics by formaly quantizing Einstein Field equations.
Skipping many interesting author claims aside (one of most interesting is that they claim that relaxation of curvature produces mass,- this is how a supposed universe expansion creates new mass), anyway one of authors claim is that :

As the universe expands, the charge and mass of electrons decreases, resulting in less interaction in the aging universe. The electron charge and mass are no longer constant. They depended on the radius of the universe at the time.

And they give relation between universe radius $L_{now}$ and electron charge, mass :
$$ e^2 = \frac{m_e}{c} = \frac{1}{c \cdot L_{now}}\ldotp  $$
Here comes the question,- Is it possible to somehow detect from the universe observations that in earlier universe stages electron coupling constants were stronger ? If so, what would be the possible detection scheme ? Or maybe it is already explored ?
Thanks.

The whole paper is pure nonsense, and basically none of the reasoning or equations make sense. It mentions some concepts used elsewhere in physics, but its implementation of them is really bad. "$e^2 = m_e / c$" doesn't even have consistent dimensions.

You've probably been pointed to this paper by some bad popsci articles written by people who don't know any physics. These sorts of articles should basically always just be ignored.

Article is printed in a very credible scientific journal- Elsevier, so it would seem that credible journal editors would no let in any nonsense material. Second,- as it is a theoretical physics article, they may use some natural units system where some constants are set to $1$ or maybe they are using some constants in dimensionless way,- that's also popular in theoretical physics branch. So this explains why expression dimensions seems inconsistent. But sometimes dimensionality problems does not invalidate core idea. Lastly, research direction that some physical constants may vary is not new.

Yes, they mention a lot of things that are not new, but their paper itself seems randomly generated. There's little connection between the sections, and most equations don't make sense. (For example, $e^2 = m_e / c$ doesn't make sense in any system of units I know people use, including natural units. Later on, they try to fit the tau mass to the radius of the solar system which is even more nonsensical.) Finally, Elsevier owns a ton of journals, including a bunch of poor ones, and this paper has nothing to do with the journal's subject of astroparticle physics.

It's not like it doesn't make sense at all. $(m_e/c) × m/(kg×s) \approx 10^{-39}$ and $e^2×1C^{−2} \approx 10^{-38}$, so it matches to within one order of magnitude error. Btw, last mentioned equation part evaluated without units gives $1/(c×46.5 Gly) × (m^2/s) \approx 10^{-36}$. To name this match "a pure coincidence" would be too cruel, no ? And an idea that relaxation of curvature produces mass,- introduces some nice symmetry in general relativity theory which was missing it. And that the universe is almost flat doesn't forbit possibility that expanding edges of it may be curved instead.

The problems of this paper start on the first pages. Even some of the basic definitions of differential geometry used (e.g. following the Ricci tensor) are not consistent or just flat-out nonsensical in the way they are presented. This alone should be enough for anyone to be highly critical of any results presented in the paper as it at best shows that sections of the paper were written in a careless manner.

@ThomasTappeiner At this point neither your comment, nor knzhou answers post question. Question is, IF electron charge and mass would depend on universe time scale, how we could verify this hypothesis from the universe observations ? Is it possible at all to approve or deny it ? Article credibility has nothing to do with my question. For example, I've read that there's an attempt to create nuclear clock based on proton vibrations instead of electron one, which would increase 1000x clock sensitivity compared to atomic clock. Such time resolution may let to measure constants variability

Normally you want to look at time variation of dimensionless quantities. There are strong bounds on variation of the fine-structure constant, which is related to the electron charge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-variation_of_fundamental_constants#Fine-structure_constant. The electron mass sets the scale of the Hydrogen atom, so I'd expect spectral features of stars/galaxies could put bounds on it. These authors claim to use primordial abundances to bound the variation in electron mass (but I haven't read it carefully): https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0247

However, even though your question exists independently of the paper by Srichan et al, I have to say I also agree with knzhou and Thomas Tappeiner that this is a bad paper and shouldn't have been published. Sabine Hossenfelder did a good job of explaining how a critical physics reviewer might read the paper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk_NjIPaZk4

@Andrew Thanks, for article "Time variation of the electron mass in the early universe and the Barrow-Magueijo model",- it's very interesting. If you could make this and your notes about spectral features of galaxies as your post answer - would be GREAT !

@Andrew I have checked Sabine critics. Well, some her points were valid while others - not so much. Not all critical thoughts in general are meaningful or valid either. Some ideas in first part of her critics were just a "word play". She was disappointed about the use of "mass can create curvature" and proposes better expression - "distribution of mass and energy fits the curvature". Now think for a minute,- what will happen if you place mass in a space with flat curvature,- it will "fit the mass distribution" and will curve accordingly, right ? Hence, you have "created the curvature".

@Andrew In the following replies she has commented one of authors formula that "they don't say what a square brackets means". But they actually DO say that, in a sentence "From Riemannian Geometry, Ricci curvature is defined as the commutator covariant derivative of a vector in a manifold in different directions". So at least in this respect Sabine is incorrect. In general,- critical physics reviewer can be also criticized as well for a bad/incorrect critics. To be able to criticize productively and in the right way,- one needs to at first fully grasp article material and be humble too.

There are many observational limits on variations in the electron-to-proton mass ratio ($\mu=m_e/m_p$) and the fine structure constant ($\alpha\propto e^2)$ over cosmological times and distances. (In general, only changes in dimensionless constants are meaningful.) Here is a sampling of few recent reviews:

Varying fundamental constants meet Hubble (2023)
Fundamental physical constants: current results in search for variations and their description (2022)
Search for Variations of Fundamental Constants (2022)
The status of varying constants: a review of the physics, searches and implications (2017)

The experimental limits come from looking at various electromagnetic emission, absorption, dispersion, and scattering spectra of objects at cosmological distances, e.g. quasars, white dwarfs, the cosmic microwave background, …. Changes in $\alpha$ or $\mu$ would effect processes such as:

atomic and molecular transitions: $\Delta E \propto \alpha^2 m_e$
plasma frequency: $\omega_p^2 \propto \alpha^2/m_e$
scattering cross sections: $\sigma \propto \alpha^2/m_e^2$

Current astrophysical limits are roughly $\dot{\alpha}/\alpha\lesssim 10^{-17}\;\mathrm{year^{-1}}$ and $\dot{\mu}/\mu \lesssim 10^{-16}\;\mathrm{year^{-1}}$.
You may also want to look at What is the proof that the universal constants (, ℏ, …) are really constant in time and space?

Indeed, these authors predictions are complete nonsense, as per current astrophysical limits per 7 billion years fine-structure constant could only change by $100 \times 7~ \text {billion years} \times 10^{-17} / \text{year} \approx 0.000007 %$ percent, while authors nonsensical above mentioned formula gives $\Delta e/e_0 \approx 40%$ (extrapolated from their "predicted" ratio $e/e_0 = \sqrt{L_0/L}$) assuming that universe 7 billions years ago was approximately half it's current size. So seems they completely ignore current observations, which makes their article obsolete.

Thanks for clearing-up the situation.
